# Which event to handle Http Response 204?

Tags: javascript, http

i have a web application which loads an iframe with a URL, i designed it to handle status 200 by adding a onload handler, however i came across a scenario in which the loaded URL returns a 204, it seems that handling 204 is different among browsers. which event should i listen for when handling 204 and related, http results?

Comment: What do you mean by `event`? What event? Status 204 is not an error, it's just an absence of content. So it's a `success`.

Comment: so onload is called? for example loading a page to an iframe?

Comment: oh, that one. Yes, I guess you're right.